# Assign variable and print

Tags: ios, swift

```
let animal["legs"] = currentAnimal.legCount

let animal["canFly"] = currentAnimal.canFly

let animal["chicken"] = currentAnimal.isSoonToBeNugget

let anim....
```

One of these is `nil`. I have about 10 of these and would like to print each value to the console without having to go

```
print(animal["legs"])
print(animal["canFly"])
print(animal["chicken"])
print(anim....)
```

What is the most concise way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just iterate trough the dictionary and print the key-value pair:

```
for (key, value) in animal {
    print("\(key) : \(value)")
}
```